# How to customize TextView inside LayoutInflater

Tags: android, textview, layout-inflater

I have a TextView inside this layout inflater which i want to customize. What can be the easy way other than implementing getView()

```
private ViewGroup buildHeader() {
        LayoutInflater infalter = getLayoutInflater();
        ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) infalter.inflate(R.layout.listitem_header, getListView(), false);

        //TEXT VIEW SET COLOR

        header.setEnabled(false);
        return(header);
      }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What inflater does is *inflate* the layout you specified to the view hierarchy.
In other words the inflater builds the objects (views) located in the layout specified, so they can be then used.

Once that is done you can find the views located in that layout with `findViewById` and manipulate them.

So if you have a layout that consists of:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="myTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can get and use your `TextView` like this:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
textView.setText("Something"):
textView.setColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: Thankyou...That worked. A place where i was making mistake was not adding "header.findViewById...Thanks once again